# no rule to make target for simple hello module

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel-module

So I am trying to write a simple hello module no need to say a newbie :)

however while following steps to create a make file - what I saw was I didnot have build folder at uname -r/**build**  so I created one - not sure that itself should be problem as in instead of creating build folder if I am suppose to download some package ?

Also looking online there is solution which says I need to do below steps

prepare-kernel-sources
**cd /usr/src/linux**  - now turns out I dont i have linux folder too
cp -rf include/generated/* include/linux/

```
make: Entering directory `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build'
make: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build'
```

I have tried to install following packages - only the highlighted ones goes through rest gives error

```
**apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)**  goes through
apt-get install Linux-headers-generic
apt-get install build-essentials
apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt-get install kernel-source-$(uname -r)
**apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)**   goes through
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Do you have the kernel development packages installed on your system?

Comment: @EtanReisner - I have updated the question with things I have tried to install post the error based on research online - but majority of things are giving me error - ln btw flavor is debian on which I am trying

Comment: And did you try compiling again after installing those two packages? (I doubt `apt-get source` is helpful here though as that probably just grabbed the sources used to build the Debian package itself.)

Comment: @EtanReisner - I have updated the answer - turns out it was because of missing system link . I have posted the answer if someone else trips on same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the answer - Missing part was establishing **system link**.

Below steps solved the issue.

```
apt-get install linux-headers 
ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64/ /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that yourself. That should be part of the   linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64 package. See [here](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64/filelist).

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'linux-headers' has no installation candidate

Comment: Under Opensuse install kernel-default-devel.

Answer (score 0):

Directory that contains Makefile and source was named with space between. changed space with underscore(_). Worked.